# track changes from the start of workspace

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse plugin. I need to keep track of the files changed/created from the plugin or outside it. I have added the Resource change Listener in the Activator of the plugin.
 But this will track the changes only after the plugin is invoked. In the mean while if any changes were made from other menus, i am not able to track them. Is there any 
  way to handle the changes that happen before the activation of my plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does not have a listener that you could add to track changes before your plugin is initialized.  You could add an IStartup extension to register your resource change listener early, but these are considered evil (it's similar to putting something in the Startup folder on windows, why start something unless you KNOW you're going to use it?).

However, it sounds like you could solve this using the IResource API and by keeping an index of the files your plugin has control over (probably using checksums).  I would add a system job on your plugin's startup to index the files and reconcile your model against what's on disk.

Another thought is that you may be able to piggy-back off of a team provider if the resources in question will be going into a repository.